# run powershell from c# application

Tags: c#, powershell

Hello a have a file with 21 lines of code in power shell. I need a way to run this file with a button in c#. I use c# in Visual Studio 2010. Please let me know if there is a way to achieve.

```
// Powershell
$Proc = Get-Process | Sort-Object CPU -Descending
$cores = Get-WmiObject Win32_processor
$memory = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem
$Total = 10
$num = 1

Clear-Content c:\scripts\prueba.txt

foreach ($objItm in $Proc) {
If ($num -gt $Total) {
    break #break the loop
}

[string] $strID=[System.Convert]::ToString($objItm.ID)
[string] $strProcessName=[System.Convert]::ToString($objItm.ProcessName)
[string] $strCPU=[System.Convert]::ToString($objItm.CPU)
[string] $strNUM=[System.Convert]::ToString($num)

$info=$strNUM+"-"+$strID+"-"+$strProcessName+"-"+$strCPU

$num += 1

$info|Add-Content c://scripts/prueba.txt

}
//Code c#
RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create(); 
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
runspace.Open(); RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline(); 
pipeline.Commands.Add(scriptFile)
Execute PowerShell script results = pipeline.Invoke();
```

I need for example press a button and make the script happens

Comment: Yes, there is a way to achieve this. What have you tried, and how much research have you done?

Comment: Well i have been looking and found a way `RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
runspace.Open();

RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.Add(scriptFile);

// Execute PowerShell script
results = pipeline.Invoke();`

Comment: but a use my sp location and doesnt work. I do not know what more need because the code wirte in the first answer was tested in powershell and work perfectly

Comment: You should be editing the OP, not posting code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PS2EXE](http://ps2exe.codeplex.com) by [Ingo Karstein](http://ikarstein.wordpress.com)

This creates a c# executable with it's own powershell host and with your script embedded.

I have a c# project which takes the c# code in PS2EXE, adds ability to read the contents of an encrypted powershell script, decrypt it and run it.

Answer (score 0):

some tips that works for me . My application is already working

1. Run Visual Studio with permissions of Administrator this to avoid get a error with the Hkey_Local...
2. In power shell run this get-executionpolicy to view the policy and set unregistered with set-executionpolicy unregistered. This avoid any restriction by the OS.

And with the code write above the app work. Get ready and test !!!